# L_1 norm optimization as a sequence of linear optimizations?

Tags: matrices, optimization, linear-programming, nonlinear-optimization

Does someone know of numerical methods to approximately solve ${\bf x_0} = \min_{\bf x}\{ \left\|\bf Mx - b\right\|_1\}$ by using some sequence of linear optimizations? Links or ideas are both welcome.

Comment: Will it still work if there is a sum of such norms?

Comment: The $L^1$-norm of a vector is itself a sum of $L^1$-norms of the components of the vector.

Comment: Yep. But say if I have $\bf M_1$ $\bf M_2$, $\bf b_1$, $\bf b_2$ and want to minimize $\bf \|M_1 x - b_1\|_1 + \| M_2 x - b_2\|_1$ those terms may want to draw x in different "directions". In the case of $L^2$ norms they would easily "merge" because of linearity, each term contributing with an additive matrix on the left hand side.

Comment: It doesn't matter. But you should not be asking one question while looking for the answer to another. Ask *exactly the question* you want help with; e.g., the sum-of-norms problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot everyone. Helped me find inspiration to last part of my thesis. :0) Ok Michael I will try to be more precise in my questions in the future.